# How to click an angular element with selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Need  help on below to click() i can't click on the Button 'Connexion'. I can locate element in Chrome devtool but my program still fails.

Button HTML :

```
<button class="btn btn-lg hoverableButton ng-scope" translate="LOGIN" ng-disabled="authenticationCtrl.disableMageConnectButton()" ng-click="onSubmit()">Connexion</button>
```

I have tried with below code

```
By button = By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-lg hoverableButton ng-scope' and contains(@ng-click, 'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')]");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button));
    webdriver.findElement(button).click();
```

The error Message :

> Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable:
> By.xpath: //button[@class='btn btn-lg hoverableButton ng-scope' and
> contains(@ng-click, 'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')] (tried for
> 15 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

and

> no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='btn btn-lg
> hoverableButton ng-scope' and contains(@ng-click,
> 'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')]"}

I tested the xpath on devtools and xpath and it found the button.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share the URL?

Comment: it's an intern website of the company you need an accout , vpn ...

Comment: what happen if you take XPath //button[text()='Connexion'] and click

Comment: i have other button in other pannel with same name and i try it with adding index like (//button[@translate='LOGIN'])[2] or //(button[contains(text(),'Connexion')])[2] i got the same error

Comment: As stated by the @cruisepandey try to check for the `iframe`

Comment: i try it with iframe id but i have this error No frame element found by name or id lightningjs-frame-usabilla_live it seems that they are not an iframe, thanks .

Comment: share the current context HTML source

Comment: Looks like that element having ng-disabled attribute i.e element will be in disable state. In those cases, waiting to element clickable will fail the condition after given timeout

Comment: @YaDavMaNish i update the question you can see the HTML source

Comment: @Sreenivasulu in this case what im supposed to do ? can you give me more indicator

Comment: Check if you have anyway to enable the element. Before applying the condition, just call isEnabled() on top of that element and check in which status it is?

Comment: Definitely there will be a use case to make it enable.. Check the use cases and try..

Comment: @jerando can you check with this... //button[@class='btn btn-lg hoverableButton' and starts-with(@ng-click, 'authenticationCtrl')][contains(., 'Connexion')]

Comment: @YaDavMaNish i got the same Error , thanks for your help

Comment: @jerando //button[@class='btn btn-lg hoverableButton ng-scope' and starts-with(@ng-click, 'authenticationCtrl')][contains(., 'Connexion')] can you check it again

Comment: @YaDavMaNish same error, thanks for your feed back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
webdriver.findElement(button).click();
```

throws

> no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='btn btn-lg
> hoverableButton ng-scope' and contains(@ng-click,
> 'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()'

It could be cause of element is in iframe or locator could not found in DOM.

Since you are saying that it is present in DOM, I would probably say, we may have an iframe issue here.

**Iframe :**

> The  tag specifies an inline frame.
>
> An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current
> HTML document.

In Selenium, we need to switch the driver focus to particular iframe in order to interact with the elements which are inside of the iframe :

```
driver.switchTo.frame("Frame_ID");
```

and then you should be able to do :

```
webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Connexion']")).click();
```

**Update 1 :**

There are two button with same name, I am pretty much sure that `xpath` index will work

**for first button :**

```
(//button[text()='Connexion'])[1]
```

**second button :**

```
(//button[text()='Connexion'])[2]
```

**Update 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//button[text()='Connexion'])[2]"))).click();
```

Comment: first thanks for your help . second i have i have other button in other pannel with same name and i try it with adding index like (//button[@translate='LOGIN'])[2] or //(button[contains(text(),'Connexion')])[2] i got the same error. third i try it with iframe id but i have this error No frame element found by name or id lightningjs-frame-usabilla_live it seems that they are not an iframe .

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste (//button[@translate='LOGIN'])[2]  and see if your desired element is getting highlighted

Comment: yes sir i can find the element in chrome devtool, when i do paste for (//button[@translate='LOGIN'])[2]  i can visualize the element but when i run my progam i got the same error message

Comment: is it 1/1 entry in DOM ? and when you scroll up you do not see an iframe ?

Comment: i updated the question so you can see the HTML, ''is it 1/1 in DOM" i didn't understand that, no they are no iframe. Thanks

Comment: do me a favor and give me the entire page source

Comment: it's update on the question you can see the code html

Comment: @jerando : thnx, can you try update 1 section.

Comment: Hello sir , i tried it for the second button i did that :

Comment: By button = By.xpath("(//button[text()='Connexion'])[2]");

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 15);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button));
  webdriver.findElement(button).click();

Comment: and i have this like all the time :

Comment: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: (//button[text()='Connexion'])[2]

Comment: and this : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//button[text()='Connexion'])[2]"}

Comment: You can directly click like this, no need to define `findElement` again.  `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 15); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button)).click()`

Comment: can't believe that, the same error even i modified the code

Comment: I have updated the answer as well, updated 2 section

Comment: sorry to bother you but it doesn't work, and I don't really know where the problem comes from

Comment: I need to see the entire real application now, before suggesting anything anymore

Comment: can i share my screen with you ?

Comment: you must have the vpn of the company and all the procedure , and an accout is better to share my screen i guess

Comment: i will send you the link zoom on your gmail

Comment: done sir youn can find the link in your email

Comment: after 30 -35 mins from now, we can meet

Comment: okay i will send you a new link in 30 mins , thanks for your time

Comment: okay sir, i ll keep an eye on it , thanks .

Comment: Sir i sent you the link for the meeting the other is not invalide because after 40min it expire